# Repair fork or get new one?

Tags: repair, fork

Right now, I have a pretty old and terrible fork: 2006 Manitou Axel Elite 100. It's leaking oil like crazy, and I've almost eaten it a few times because of how easy it is to bottom out the forks. I pretty much have to ride with lockout on.

So my question is what would it take to repair them so that they are usable? Would it even be worth it?

If I just need to get a new fork, what should I get? I haven't needed to upgrade anything for a while, so I'm out of date on everything. I really don't want to spend more than $150, but I'm fine buying used. Is there something besides Ebay I should look?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @m0ngr31. Please check out our [help] to see why we don't do product recommendations, price checks, website recs, and he like (the short answer is that they get out of date quickly). As it is, this question will be closed, so I suggest that you click the edit button to change your last para to be much more general, about characteristics to look for.

Comment: If you have disc brakes you have options for a new fork. If you have rim brakes, a new fork is pretty much out the question (it would be a cheap pogo stick). This means used - and you are as likely to end up with something the same as you have.  You existing fork may just need a service and new seals (although they we never great forks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your time isn't worth much and you like to tinker (like me), at least take your current fork apart and see if there's anything you could do to improve it's situation.

That said, based on your description of it's problems, I think you should buy a new one. And I actually mean new, in this case. Normally it's better to buy a used bike than a new one, but with something that's as age-sensitive as a suspension fork, I'd buy a new one (and take care of it, maybe get a stanchion boot).

As to what fork you should get... take note of the specs of your current fork (brake options, wheel size, stanchion size, travel) and get something similar. $150 will get you something decent.

If you decide to get something new, Amazon, Ebay, and your LBS are good places to look.